# Displaying JSON data nicely in Swift 3

Tags: swift

I'm quite new to swift and I'm trying to display JSON data received from a server in 3 columns, however, I'd like the text to line up and possibly remove the brackets surrounding each bit of text. I've attached an image below, along with my code.

[image: Swift Screenshot]

```
   let u = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "userIP")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://\(u):3000/logs")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString = "LockID=\(lockid)"
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
                print("error=\(error)")
                return
            }

            if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
                print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                print("response = \(response)")
                 DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                self.displayMyAlertMessage("response = \(response)")
                }
            }

            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
         //   print("responseString = \(responseString)")

            if let data = responseString?.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                let resString = JSON(data: data)

                if resString["success"].stringValue == "true"
                {
                  //  save the data to be manipulated and stored in table somehow
                    let returned_name =  resString["message"].arrayValue.map({$0["name"].stringValue})
                    let returned_time =  resString["message"].arrayValue.map({$0["lockTime"].stringValue})
                    let returned_type =  resString["message"].arrayValue.map({$0["type"].stringValue})

                    DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                        self.updatename!.text = "\(returned_name.description)"
                        self.updateLock!.text = " \(returned_type.description)"
                        self.updateText!.text = " \(returned_time.description)"

                }

                }
                else if resString["success"].stringValue == "false"
                {
                     DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                    self.displayMyAlertMessage(resString["message"].stringValue)
                    }
                }
```

Im maniplulating the JSON data with SwiftyJSON. Any ideas on how i can strip out the [""]?

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

`returned_name` and the other `returned...` variables is an **array** of strings caused by the `map` function. Printing an array using the `description` method displays `"[item1, item2, item3]"`. To print each string separately you need a repeat loop.

```
  let returnedArray = resString["message"].arrayValue // you might cast the object to `[[String:Any]]`
  for item in returnedArray {
      print(item["name"])
      print(item["lockTime"])
      print(item["type"])
  }
```

To display the values in a table view you need a model, the best way is a custom struct

```
struct Item {
   let name : String
   let lockTime : String
   let type : String
}
```

Then create a data source array

```
var items : [Item]()
```

And map your received JSON to the model

```
  let returnedArray = resString["message"].arrayValue
  for item in returnedArray {
      let name = item["name"] ?? ""
      let lockTime = item["lockTime"] ?? ""
      let type = item["type"] ?? ""
      items.append(Item(name:name, lockTime:lockTime, type:type))
  }
```

Put the code to parse the JSON in `viewDidLoad` and call `reloadData()` at the end, in `cellForRow` get the item for the row from the array and display the values for example:

```
let item = items[indexPath.row]
self.updatename!.text = item.name
self.updateLock!.text = item.lockTime
self.updateText!.text = item.type
```

PS: since you are new to Swift don't use snake case variable names (`returned_name`), use camel case (`returnedName`).

Comment: Thanks for your help! Just out of curiosity, is there a reason to use camel case over snake case?

Comment: It's the naming convention in Objective-C and Swift